# How to fix "ValueError: An initializer for variable conv2d/kernel of is required" when opencv and tensorflow is used

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I am writing a program which is supposed to use tensorflow and opencv to
perform sign language recognition with use of Convolutional Neural Networks.
I used examplary code for MNIST classifier which can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/layers/cnn_mnist.py) and
I tried to change it in such manner that I could use opencv to load training
images and then camera capture as an input for CNN.
Right now, I have a problem with training of the model which reveals itself
in an error:

***ValueError: An initializer for variable conv2d/kernel of  is required***

Whole error log can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/HHU62DAQ)

**Versions of frameworks in use:**

- Tensorflow r 1.7.1
- OpenCV 4.0.0
- Python 3.6.5
- Numpy 1.14.2

The code that is supposed to prepare training data for the network can be seen
in the first code snippet. It just reads a bunch of jpg photos whith different
hand gestures, resizes those images and puts it into numpy array

```
def prepareTrainingData(trainingLetterMaxId, training_image_size):
    training_images = []
    training_labels = []
    for letter in training_letters:
        for i in range(0, trainingLetterMaxId):
            read_image = cv2.imread('/home/radkye/Documents/ASLRecognizer/images/'
            + letter + '/' + letter + '_' + str(i) + '.jpg', 0)
            resized = np.array(cv2.resize(read_image, (training_image_size, training_image_size)))
            flattened = resized.ravel()
            image = tf.cast(flattened, tf.float32)
            training_images.append(image)
            net_output = np.zeros(len(training_letters))
            net_output[letters_to_indices_map[letter]] = 1
            training_labels.append(net_output)

    result = np.array(training_images)
    labels_result = np.array(training_labels)
    return result, labels_result

training_data, training_labels = prepareTrainingData(100, 60)
train_labels_int = np.asarray(training_labels, dtype=np.int32)

mnist_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn=cnn.cnn_model_fn,
    model_dir="/home/radkye/Documents/studia/ASLRecognizer_AutoTestVersion/asl_cnn_model")

tensors_to_log = {"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}
logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(
    tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=50)

train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"x": training_data},
    y=train_labels_int,
    batch_size=3600,
    num_epochs=None,
    shuffle=True)

mnist_classifier.train(
    input_fn=train_input_fn,
    steps=20000,
    hooks=[logging_hook])
```

The cnn_model_fn is defined as:

```
def cnn_model_fn(features, labels, mode):

    input_layer = tf.reshape(features["x"], [-1, 60, 60, 1])

    conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs=input_layer,
        filters=64,
        kernel_size=[5, 5],
        padding="same",
        activation=tf.nn.relu)

    pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)

    conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs=pool1,
        filters=64,
        kernel_size=[5, 5],
        padding="same",
        activation=tf.nn.relu)

    pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)
    pool2_flat = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 12 * 12 * 64])
    dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)

    dropout = tf.layers.dropout(
        inputs=dense, rate=0.4, training=mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)

    logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=24)
```

Please, can someone help me to recognize what can be the problem with data
structure that I passed into the CNN model? The problem is probaby with the way I prepared training data which can be seen in first code snippet.
I am not that fluent in tensorflow yet.

Otherwise, maybe someone has any tutorial or example where opencv is used along with tensorflow to create CNN. I did not manage to find something
I need in this manner.

I would be very grateful for any kind of help.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`[-1, 12 * 12 * 64]` - given the padding and maxpool layers, this should be `[-1, 15 * 15 * 64]`, because 60 / 2 / 2 = 15

That said, I'm not sure that's the actual or only problem, because I don't have a way to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thank you. That's kinda stupid of me that I calculated it wrongly.
I updated the values to 15 and, unfortunately, interpreter errors did not change at all.

Comment: Bummer :( If I were you, I'd recode the whole network in Keras and use Tensorflow only as a backend. With Keras you don't get cryptic errors like this.